# Sql join without replacement, so a row is only joined once?

Tags: sql, join

Let’s say I have two tables, teams and Quarterbacks.

-Teams-

```
Patriots
Buccaneers
```

-Quarterbacks

```
Tom Brady
Cam Newton
```

I want to “allocate” players to teams using sql, but I don’t want Tom Brady on every team. Once joined to a team, I want the qb row ineligible for subsequent joining, I want join without replacement.

Answer (score 0):

If the tables have the same number of rows (as in your example), you can generate a sequence number using `row_number()` and `join`:

```
select t.team, q.quarterback
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by team) as seqnum
      from teams t
     ) t join
     (select q.*, row_number() over (order by quarterback) as seqnum
      from quarterbacks q
     ) q
     on t.seqnum = q.seqnum
```